# Allow agent forwarding using Cmder (ConEmu)

Tags: git, shell, ssh, command-prompt, cmder

I am using [cmder](http://cmder.net/) which runs [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/) on Windows 8.1.

It has a built in Git functionality so I can pull/push git repositories in the console (like on a Linux console)

To authenticate I use a password protected SSH private key. If I do a `git push` With ConEmu, it will prompt me for the keys password each time. I can type 'start-ssh-agent' and enter my password once, and it will will auto-authenticate me in that ConEmu window, however if I close or open another window I need to run the command again.

How can I start an ssh-agent that will authenticate my key in every ConEmu window?

Comment: Looks like you really want a Linux system ;) About the topic, you need to start an ssh-agent globally to make it available across the system. Something like putty-agent comes in mind on Windows

Comment: You may create startup [task](http://conemu.github.io/en/Tasks.html) where you run [ssh-agent](http://conemu.github.io/en/SshAgent.html) and [export](http://conemu.github.io/en/ConEmuEnvironment.html#Export_variables) variables `SSH_AGENT_PID` and `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` to ConEmu and its consoles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the following [snipped](https://gist.github.com/bojanrajkovic/6997145eda613467ace4) the SSH key is added during the startup of Cmder and the password has only be entered once per session:

```
@echo off
ssh-agent | grep -v echo | sed -e "s/^/@set /" | sed -e "s/;.*$//" - > call.cmd
call call.cmd
del call.cmd
ssh-add "%HOME%\.ssh\id_rsa"
@echo on
```

Add the code to `cmder/config/user-profile.cmd` in the current Cmder version or to `cmder/vendor/init.bat` for older versions.

**Edit:**
Newer versions of cmder have the following lines in the `user-profile.cmd` which does the same using git:

```
:: uncomment this to have the ssh agent load when cmder starts
call "%GIT_INSTALL_ROOT%/cmd/start-ssh-agent.cmd"
```

Comment: As of the latest cmder, the file to update would be `cmder\config\user-profile`. The snippet still works great!